# Apache Pig Quantile Grouping

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, conditional-operator, quantile

I am working to find some solution to a grouping problem with Pig. Currently I have a dataset that looks like;

```
Group | Height | Weight
  A   | 96.5   | 110.2
  B   | 88.2   | 122.5
  A   | 94.1   | 100.8
  B   | 84.1   | 115.6
```

I am using the StreamingQuantile method from the DataFu library to compute the quantiles (25th,50th...etch) on the height variable. Currently it works, but I also need to compute the AVG weight for each of the groups + their quantiles; So it would look something like this;

```
A | Quantile1 | 88.5 (height)  | 134.4 (avg weight)
A | Quantile2 | 125.3 (height) | 156.2 (avg weight)
etc.....
B | Quantile4 | 144.3 (height) | 134.2 (avg weight)
```

For reference, here is the simple Pig for computing the quantiles;

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
define Quantile datafu.pig.stats.StreamingQuantile('0.0','0.25','0.5','0.75','1.0');
A = load 'mydata';
Group_A = GROUP A BY $0;
Quant = FOREACH GROUP_A GENERATE group,Quantile(A.$1);
```

Is there anyway I can also calculate the average of $2 for each quantile and group?

Answer (score 0):

I named the columns to avoid confusion.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/datafu-1.2.0.jar;
define Quantile datafu.pig.stats.StreamingQuantile('0.0','0.25','0.5','0.75','1.0');
A = load 'mydata' using PigStorage('|') as (grouping:chararray, height:double, weight:double);
Group_A = GROUP A BY grouping;
Quant = FOREACH GROUP_A GENERATE group, Quantile(A.height) as q;
joined = join Quant by group, A by grouping;
grouped = group joined by (grouping, q)
average = foreach grouped generate group, AVG(joined.weight);
```